# Getting multiple strings of the same lenght from array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, line

i need to take the longest line, or multiple if there is, out of string array of lines and write it out in console together with its posision in the array, i managed to find  the longest one but im unable to find multiple strings. Can anyone help? (sorry if this is hard to understand).

Comment: You should show the code you've used to find the longest line so we can see where you need help.

Comment: "(sorry if this is hard to understand)" -- yes, it is. We like code and example data. [mcve]

Comment: Instead of writing ("sorry if this is hard to understand")
You should try to explain better what you want to archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is store the longest lines and their indexes in a dictionary. Start with a temporary variable to hold the longest line, and then walk through the array. As we find lines that are equal length, add them to our dictionary. If we find a longer line, set the dictionary to a new one, with just that line added to it, and continue.

For example:

```
public static void PrintLongestLinesAndIndexes(string[] input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No data");
        return;
    }

    var longestLine = string.Empty;
    var longestLines = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // If this line is longer, reset our variables
        if (input[i].Length > longestLine.Length)
        {
            longestLine = input[i];
            longestLines = new Dictionary<int, string> {{i, input[i]}};
        }
        // If it's the same length, add it to our dictionary
        else if (input[i].Length == longestLine.Length)
        {
            longestLines.Add(i, input[i]);
        }
    }

    foreach (var line in longestLines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"'{line.Value}' was found at index: {line.Key}");
    }
}
```

Then we can use it like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PrintLongestLinesAndIndexes(new[]
    {
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    });

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Another way to do this would be to use `Linq` to select the items and their indexes, group them by the item's length, then order them by the length and select the first group:

```
public static void PrintLongestLinesAndIndexes(string[] input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        input.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
            .GroupBy(i => i.item.Length)
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.Key)
            .First()
            .Select(line => $"'{line.item}' was found at index: {line.index}")));
}
```